# Turn off Visual Studio animation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have C++ project in my Visual Studio 2019. If I press Ctrl+F find window appears with some delay and possible animation. Usually I press Ctrl+F and Ctrl+V and search phrase appears in code. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try playing around with the settings under "Tools | Options | General", particularly "Automatically adjust visual experience". Try deaktivating "automatically adjust...", then enable or disable "rich client"/"hardware graphics"...

Also some plugins like VisualAssist or others that have a visual component may slow down rendering, especially when used with Remote Desktop.